# Logformat for catching asked hostname in a *.domain.com scenario?

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I have an Apache 2.2 VirtualHost with a *.example.com `ServerName`. This is required for my scenario, all subdomains are handled with the same site.

Now, in the access log, I am trying to figure out a `LogFormat` variable (or way) that will let me log the **asked for** domain name. If I use the `vhost_combined` format, all I get in my access log is *.example.com entries, not the actual vhost that was *asked for*.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `%{headername}i` to put the contents of any header in the LogFormat directive, so `%{Host}i` will give you what the client put in the Host: header of the request, giving you exactly what you want.

See docs at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html

Answer (score 5):

When you're using e.g. the `vhost_combined` Logformat:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log vhost_combined
```

You can adapt `vhost_combined` by adding `%{Host}i`, e.g.

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t %{Host}i \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
```